# Error handling data from XML document

Tags: php, xml

I am getting information from an XML document and for the most part everything runs as it should. Occasionally, I get a php fatal error Call to a member function children() on a non-object. I have tried to use this

```
if(isset($current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount))
{
    $listPrice = $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
} else {
    $listPrice = 0;
}
```

to catch any times there is no information in `$current`, but it does not always work. How do I handle the errors so it works all the time?

Comment: This should really be moved to SO as this is not a request for a review, but for help. Also, you might think about adding more information. There isn't nearly enough here to answer this question. A sample from the XML would be helpful, as would a full error stack.

Comment: I think it depends what is being reviewed here.  The error handling approach can be commented upon at least.

Comment: True, and for the OP to have gotten this deep into the XML tree I would have expected those pointers to have been abstracted more first. Instead it appears that he is navigating directly to them, which is causing some really unnecessary repetition and could cause mistakes/typos in the future. Try using variables to abstract the different sections of that XML while you are parsing it, such as `$attributes = $current->AttributeSets;` etc...

Comment: The tree is pretty large, and $current holds all of the items that are static.  Once I need to get custom variables, ie list price, then I just go to them directly ($current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that your check can fail.  Before you can call the `children` method you need to be sure that you are dealing with an object (that provides the `children` method).  This is actually what your fatal error is telling you (`$current->AttributeSets` is a non-object).  You get this in your if statement within your `isset` call.

The trouble with fatal errors is that they are fatal.  There is no way to recover from them.  The PHP engine is about to shutdown.  You can read more about handling errors in an answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10538836#10538836).  The only way is to avoid fatal errors.  Don't call functions that don't exist, or methods on something that is `NULL`.

Possibly the reason you have this problem is breaking the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).  I don't know how the XML objects you are working with are built, etc.

You could solve it by checking each component.

Unfortunately you **can't** do this because `isset` can't use a function's return value:

```
// THIS WON'T WORK
isset($current->AttributeSets,
      $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)) // Function Return Value
```

However as [mseancole commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15158/error-handling-data-from-xml-document/15184#comment24667_15158) you can set the components as variables.

```
if (isset($current->AttributeSets))
{
    $children = $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true);

    if (isset($children,
              $children->ItemAttributes,
              $children->ItemAttributes->ListPrice, // etc.
```

Comment: does it matter if the information from the xml document is extracted as a simple_load_string in the function?  I was trying your suggestion and it was not working.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: sorry, i have fixed it.  It basically becomes what mseancole wrote in the comment.  @mseancole I'd be happy to upvote your comment if it was an answer (I think it really is very appropriate advice).